# passing data to the fancy box using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

i want to know how to pass information from my the page to fancybox(lightbox) using jquery. i want to pass the information typed in the textbox(.question_box) when clicking the addButton to bring up a fancybox.
html:

```
<input class="question_box" type="text">
<a id="addButton" class="pop_up" href="add_note.html">Ask Question!</a>
```

jquery:

```
/* Configuring the fancybox plugin for the "Add a note" button: */
    $("#addButton").fancybox({
        'zoomSpeedIn'       : 600,
        'zoomSpeedOut'      : 500,
        'easingIn'          : 'easeOutBack',
        'easingOut'         : 'easeInBack',
        'hideOnContentClick': false,
        'padding'           : 15
    });
```

Comment: What page does this button appear on? What content is found on add_note.html? Do you want the fancybox to contain only the typed content? Is a different template supposed to appear in fancybox with the typed content included?

Comment: That code looks like it will do what you want just fine, perhaps you could elaborate on exactly what you want this code to do, and what it is not doing that you want it to?

Comment: yeh im sorry i forget to mention that on the add_note.html thiers a textbox thier (.input_from_page) that is mean to get the value from (.question_box) :)) sorry about the misunderstanding!!

Comment: Just having the a's href link to "add_note.html" will not make it submit the question.

Comment: i dnt get what you mean, the href='add_note.html' is the actual page of the fancybox, i just want to pass the data from the input to that page, so i can display it :), the add_note.html will do the sumbitting the question!!!

Comment: You realize that a link DOES NOT submit data. It simply changes the URL of the browser. For this, you need to use a FORM. On top of that, a .HTML page cannot receive "POST" data, only "GET" data. Unless, of course, you are using URL rewrites.

Comment: thats what i want GET DATA, not POST!!! i just want to get the input value(.question_box) :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:
Get value from textbox put it into the link of #addButton

```
$('.question_box').keyup(function(){
   $('#addButton').attr('href', 'add_note.html?str=' + $(this).val());
})
```

In add_note.html use this function to get the parameter

```
function getParameterByName( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery)

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, when i get the paramter using var value= getParametereByname(str); how can i print value inside my textbox? :))

Comment: You can use $('#your_textbox_id').val(getParametereByname(str));

Comment: Did you include jquery library in add_note.html? This code $('#your_textbox_id') need jquery. And did you check the link is generated and passed correctly? You can see it in Firebug.

Comment: yes i have :( now it load properly, but the value is not getting passsed http://www.pastie.org/1677015 this is my full script

Comment: Sorry, the code should like this: $('#note-body').val(getParameterByName('str'));

Comment: Please make sure the function getParameterByName() is correct. I mistyped the function name in my above comment. I tested the code and it works for me.

Comment: yeh i found that bug aswell, and it corrected when i paste the pastie. but it still deosnt work!! can you show me your code!!

Answer (score 1):

The proper HTML is:

```
<form action="add_note.html" method="GET">
<input class="question_box" name="question" type="text" />
<button id="addButton" class="pop_up" href="add_note.html">Ask Question!</button>
</form>
```

And your add_note.html should look for the GET data "question".

Comment: thank do i get the data in add_note.html using html or php lol thakns:)) +1 upvote from me

Comment: You can use javascript or PHP. If you wish to simply display the question to the user when the page goes to add_note.html, use javascript. If you wish to save and display the question, use PHP. BTW, you should click the check mark, not the upvote ;)